# Calculate column-wise mean of rows of a numpy matrix selected using values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Given a numpy array `M` of shape `(r, c)` e.g.

```
M = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15]])  # r = 5; c = 3
```

and a one-dimensional array `a` of length `r`, containing integers that can vary from 0 to `k-1`, e.g.

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 2, 1, 0])  # k = 4
```

I want to use the values in `a` to select rows from `M` to get an intermediate result like this:

```
array([
       [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [13, 14, 15]]  # rows of M where a == 0
       [[10, 11, 12]],                       # rows of M where a == 1
       [[7, 8, 9]]                           # rows of M where a == 2
       []                                    # rows of M where a == 3 (there are none)
      ])
```

(I don't need this intermediate array, but am just showing it for illustration.) The returned result would be a `(k, c)` array with the column-wise means from this array:

```
array([[ 6.,  7.,  8.],   # means where a == 0
   [10., 11., 12.],       # means where a == 1
   [ 7.,  8.,  9.],       # etc.
   [nan, nan, nan]])
```

I can do this with

```
np.array([M[a == i].mean(axis=0) for i in range(k)])
```

but is there a way (hopefully faster for large `r` and `k`) that purely uses numpy methods instead of using a for loop to make a list (which will then have to be converted back to an array)?

Comment: you cannot have a non-rectangular array as you described, but you ca have your final output as array.

Comment: can you use pandas or do you want pure numpy?

Comment: @Ehsan thanks, I have edited the question - I don't need the non-rectangular intermediate array.

Comment: @Ehsan I'm looking for a numpy method to optimize speed

Comment: Oh I already posted a pandas one. I will post a numpy later if there was none. I would suggest for speed to try numba with loop though, might be faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

NumPy solution leveraging BLAS powered matrix-multiplication -

```
In [46]: m = a == np.arange(k)[:,None] #or np.equal.outer(np.arange(k), a)

In [47]: m.dot(M)/m.sum(1,keepdims=True)
Out[47]: 
array([[ 6.,  7.,  8.],
       [10., 11., 12.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
```

For performance boost on larger arrays, convert the mask to float and use `np.bincount` for counting mask elements -

```
In [108]: m.astype(float).dot(M)/np.bincount(a,minlength=k)[:,None]
Out[108]: 
array([[ 6.,  7.,  8.],
       [10., 11., 12.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
```

**Approach #2**

Another with `np.bincount` applied across columns -

```
n = M.shape[1]
out = np.empty((k,n))
for i in range(n):
    out[:,i] = np.bincount(a,M[:,i], minlength=k) 
out /= np.bincount(a,minlength=k)[:,None]
```

#### Benchmarking

Benchmarking all approaches listed in @Ehsan's post.

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions :

```
import benchit
funcs = [m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6]
in_ = {(nr,nc,k):[np.random.randint(100,size=(nr,nc)), np.random.randint(0,k,size=nr), k] for nr in [100,1000,10000,100000] for nc in [10,100,200] for k in [10, 100, 1000]}
t = benchit.timings([m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6], in_, multivar=True, input_name=['nrows','ncols','k'])
t.plot(logx=True, save='timings.png')
```

[image]

Since, `m6` is the original one. Let's get the speedups w.r.t.
to it :

```
t.speedups(m6).plot(logx=True, logy=True, save='speedups.png')
```

[image]

There's no clear winner across all datasets. Nevertheless, `m5` seems to be good with small ncols, while `m1` seems better on bigger ncols.

Comment: Accepting because Approach 2 seems fastest for a good range of matrix lengths and values of `k`, as long as the matrix is not very wide

Comment: @Stuart Added some detailed plotting to make things clear. Still no clear winner across all variations.

Answer (score 5):

A pandas solution (Thanks to @Quang for suggestion on a better code):

```
pd.DataFrame(M).groupby(a).mean().reindex(np.arange(k)).values
#[[ 6.  7.  8.]
# [10. 11. 12.]
# [ 7.  8.  9.]
# [nan nan nan]]
```

---

Comparison using @Divakar's `benchit`:

```
#@Ehsan's solution
def m1(M, a):
  return pd.DataFrame(M).groupby(a).mean().reindex(np.arange(k)).values

#@Divakar's solution 1
def m2(M, a):
  m = a == np.arange(k)[:,None] #or np.equal.outer(np.arange(k), a)
  return m.dot(M)/m.sum(1,keepdims=True)

#@Mad Physicist's solution 1
def m3(M, a):
    index = np.argsort(a)
    a = a[index]
    M = M[index]
    split = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[-1, a]))
    means = np.add.reduceat(M, split, axis=0) / np.diff(np.r_[split, a.size])[:, None]
    result = np.full((k, M.shape[1]), np.nan)
    result[a[split], :] = means
    return result

#@Mad Physicist's solution 2
def m4(M, a):
    u, ind, cnt = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    ind = np.argsort(ind)
    split = np.cumsum(np.r_[0, cnt[:-1]])
    result = np.full((k, M.shape[1]), np.nan)
    result[u, :] = np.add.reduceat(M[ind], split, axis=0) / cnt[:, None]
    return result

#@Divakar's solution 2
def m5(M, a):
  n = M.shape[1]
  out = np.empty((k,n))
  for i in range(n):
      out[:,i] = np.bincount(a,M[:,i], minlength=k) 
  out /= np.bincount(a,minlength=k)[:,None]
  return out

#@OP's baseline
def m6(M, a):
  return np.array([M[a == i].mean(axis=0) for i in range(k)])

funcs = [m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6]
in_ = {n:[np.random.randint(100,size=(n,10)), np.random.randint(0,k,size=n)] for n in [100,1000,10000,100000]}
```

I think depending on number of your clusters and columns and rows, different approaches can be more efficient.

for **k=10**

[image]

for **k=100**

[image]

for **k=1000**

[image]

for **k=100** and `in_ = {n:[np.random.randint(100,size=(n,1000)), np.random.randint(0,k,size=n)] for n in [100,1000,10000]}`  (`M` with 1000 columns and smaller range of rows)

[image]

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(M).groupby(a).mean().reindex(np.arange(k))`

Comment: You don't need a new column for groupby just to drop it later.

Comment: Aah did not notice that. Thank you. Editing the post accordingly.

Comment: Can you add Divakar and me?

Comment: I've added another one. +1 for an elegant solution and the always-appreciated benchmarks

Comment: I'm curious to see the dependence on `k`

Comment: It is hard to depict it in a 2-D image. But I will add couple of other k value images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the benchmarking! Any way you could add my original solution for comparison? The `m5` function doesn't return anything - is it possible that affects the benchmarks? Also I note that `m5` uses a for loop over the columns in `M`, so might perform less well with wider matrices.

Comment: @Stuart Please find all the detailed changes in the post to address all your points in the comment. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! If you have time I would also love to see @Divakar's performance boosted version of m2!

Comment: @Stuart you are welcome. It is not going to make a huge difference I think.

Answer (score 5):

A pure numpy solution would require finding the sort order that puts the rows of `M` into groups. For example:

```
index = np.argsort(a)
```

You could then find the split points:

```
split = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[-1, a[index]]))
```

And then apply `np.add.reduceat` to the result to get sums:

```
sums = np.add.reduceat(M[index], split, axis=0)
```

Another `diff` gives the divisors:

```
lengths = np.diff(np.r_[split, a.size])
```

You can fill in the result using the indices encoded in `a`:

```
result = np.full((k, M.shape[1]), np.nan)
result[a[index][split], :] = sums / lengths[:, None]
```

All in all:

```
def m3(M, a, k):
    index = np.argsort(a)
    a = a[index]
    M = M[index]
    split = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[-1, a]))
    means = np.add.reduceat(M, split, axis=0) / np.diff(np.r_[split, a.size])[:, None]
    result = np.full((k, M.shape[1]), np.nan)
    result[a[split], :] = means
    return result
```

The solution can be made more concise using `np.unique`, which pre-computes the split points and indices for you. You will have to argsort the indices to invert them, and apply cumulative sum to get the correct split points:

```
def m4(M, a, k):
    u, ind, cnt = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    ind = np.argsort(ind)
    split = np.cumsum(np.r_[0, cnt[:-1]])
    result = np.full((k, M.shape[1]), np.nan)
    result[u, :] = np.add.reduceat(M[ind], split, axis=0) / cnt[:, None]
    return result
```